# Why isn't QTimer asynchronous?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I tried to use a simple `QTimer` object on my window widget so that I can calculate the elapsed time a method takes to complete. But to my astonishment, the timer was blocked until the method completes execution! i.e when the method in question ends, the timer starts ticking!

Here is a sample code to demonstrate what I wrote:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private slots:
  void on_btnTest_clicked();
  void OnTimerTick();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  ulong seconds;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And this is the cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtCore>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_btnTest_clicked()
{
  QTimer * timer = new QTimer(0);
  seconds =0;
  connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(OnTimerTick()));

  timer->setInterval(100);
  timer->start();

 QThread::sleep(5);//simulating a method which takes 5 seconds to complete

 //timer->stop();   

}

void MainWindow::OnTimerTick()
{
  ui->lblElapsedTime->setText(QString::number(++seconds));
}
```

How can I get the asynchronous behavior, something like what we have in C# i.e. where the Timer runs its own thread of execution?

**Update:**
Thanks for the clarification, now  how can I incorporate Qthreads with the timer, Do I have to inherit from Qthreads and use timer in my child class or do I have to inherit from QTimer and have a thread executed in it! It's really confusing!

Comment: What is `QThread::sleep(5)` ?

Comment: simulating the working method!

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `QElapsedTime`? `QTimer` is for triggering some work after a certain time passes.

Comment: Yes, Im trying to lets say, make a stopwatch if you will, where till the method ends, it would continue ticking every lets say 1000 ms. when the method in question completes I would stop the timer. ( I removed the part here, since the timer starts just afte the method ends, and thus stops immediately)

Comment: A single thread of execution physically can't, at the same time, sleep (or do whatever work you eventually plan to do) and handle timer click event. If you want to do two things at the same time, you need at least two threads. See `QThread`. Typically, you would offload long-running processing to a worker thread, so as not to block the UI.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes thats what I usually do, but in this case the Qtimer behavior was wierd to me, since in C# it runs in its own thread of execution and I wouldnt worry about that. 
So QTimer is not asynchronous at all really?

Comment: `QTimer` works by posting events to the owning thread's event queue. Where they sit until that thread gets around to pumping the queue. Which it wouldn't as long as it's busy handling a previous event, like for example "btnTest was clicked". If you want `QTimer` to run in its own thread of execution, then create a new thread of execution and have that thread create a `QTimer`.

Comment: Since you're using opencv, you can use getTickCount() and getTickFrequency()

Comment: @Miki: The whole idea of using the timer, is to show the elapsed time in realtime, maybe my choice of wording is not precise, but I have an application that I need to show to user, how long its been running, so I must use timer and nothing else . (I recently ran couple of my app  instances each for different  periods of time, one had been running for 2 days, and the others started running days later, and it wasnt apparent which one was running longer, So It made me think of timer .(I know I can justuse dates when some app runs, but I like Timers better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is common behavior for Qt, WinForms, WPF etc.

All UI-related events are executed synchronously one-by-one on the UI thread. Event handlers are not expected to perform long executions to avoid blocking. If you want to execute a long task, you should do it in other thread.

[`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) is designed to raise events on the UI thread. This is good because you are sure that no other event handlers are executing at that moment.

Comment: This is not the common behavior for WinForms as far as I know. 
In WinForms Timer runs in its thread and runs parallel to the UI-thread.
The confusion came from this very difference between Qt and WinForms in first place. 
(to my humble opinion, this is even not logical for timer to run in the UI thread in first place!)

Comment: @Hossein, You are wrong. WinForms Timer runs on UI thread too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot, didnt know that, I wonder how winform timer works then (maybe calling the processEvent() at back stage!)
Anywa, I would be grateful to see how I can incorporate Qthreads with timer, Do I have to inherit from Qthreads  and use timer in my child class or do I have to inherit from QTimer and have a thread executed in it! 
Its really confusing!